# Can I activate an iPhone without an Apple ID?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-id

I've been issued an iPhone and I can't seem to use it without an Apple ID.

Can I activate my phone without creating an Apple ID in the process?

Comment: Activation does not require you to sign into an Apple ID. Activation is carrier specific, if it is not working try another SIM card or take it in to be looked at.

Comment: Can you add a picture of whatever screen you are stuck with?

Comment: It’s fine to despise Apple, but keeping private data secure requires Apple to design a way to know who the owner of a device is before you put your data on that device. https://www.apple.com/privacy/ Are you looking for a jailbreak to bypass this first step or just the more pragmatic answer that this isn’t trivially bypassed?

Comment: Note that the Apple ID that is needed for app store need not be the same as for email and also could differ from any AppleID you use on your personal devices

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming you are on the first Apple ID screen below, tap "Forgot password or don't have an Apple ID?". From there, there is an option to set up an Apple ID later (or not at all) in Settings.

[image: first screen]
[image: second screen]

Comment: Can you still download (free) apps?

Comment: Don't have enough reputation yet to post a comment. However, to answer the question whether you could still download free apps without an apple ID, the answer is simply no. To use the App Store, an Apple ID is required

Comment: @Aequitas To answer why, you have to notice that Apple has to know from which country you come from and how old you are otherwise it can't know whether the app is even allowed on the given market, given audience (children) and that it is free in the given country. For that, they need full registration including personal data.

Comment: And chances are, if they were issued an iPhone, they are going to have a certain app that needs to be downloaded for company use.  This means Apple ID.  If they just wanted to issue a company phone, they'd probably give something cheaper.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Not necessarily, my work issues iPhones to anyone salary, despite just wanting them to have it for phone calls and email.